# How to store files in djangos array field

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm playing around with django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField in django 1.8 alpha and try using it with a file field.

Here's a post in a fictional forum:

```
# coding=utf-8
from backend.core.models import Team
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import FileField


class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    content = models.TextField()

    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='posts')

    attachments = ArrayField(FileField(), null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The migration worked and everything is looking great.

However: Django Admin does not support this field.

How would I implement that in code, how can I store / add a new file to this array field and store it's reference in the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, I think the `django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField` is in active development. The `django.contrib` package is [new to django 1.8](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/mjtamlyn/improved-postgresql-support-in-django) (which is still in beta) so I think this functionality is too early to count on.

The text field you are seeing is meant to be a delimited string which is saved in the array. It kinda makes sense with an array of `FileFields` because the `FileField` saves a URL string and not a blob of the file (as far as I can tell).

A `\d table` gives the table information on that column as follows:

```
arrayexample=# \d example_post
Column      | Type                     | Modifiers
--------------------------------------------------
attachments | character varying(100)[] |
```

Currently the field you are seeing in admin is created from [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa9cb5dcdc816fe0e606b8f1020d53526e08b0d4/django/contrib/postgres/forms/array.py#L13). Notice it inherits from `forms.CharField` while a `FileField` uses [forms.ClearableFileInput](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa9cb5dcdc816fe0e606b8f1020d53526e08b0d4/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L112).

I don't think the functionality you are looking for currently exists in Django but I think it is feasible to build it. Personally, I would approach building it by subclassing the existing `ArrayField` and overriding the [formfield](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fa9cb5dcdc816fe0e606b8f1020d53526e08b0d4/django/contrib/postgres/fields/array.py#L154) to use my custom `form_class` to better handle an `Array` of `FileField`s.

I hope this helps, I also don't see any open pull requests for this feature.

Comment: Hoped for another answer, but fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [FileField.storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage) which handles the storage and retrieval of files. For more details, refer Django's documentation on [Managing Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/files/)

Comment: I tried sth like this: https://dpaste.de/Lpbb

The storage is indeed working, it gets even uploaded to s3, but however, the tricky part is: How to inject this into the arrayfield?